# PHP MySQL Insert info into database from a form

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error, where-clause

I'm currentely working on some project for my school in which I have to create a profile page where people can put their information throught the input form. The data is send to database and after that displayed in some nice table.

But on my way I have encountered some problems - this is an error that I'm echoing:

> INSERT INTO `info` (`name`, `surname`, `gender`, `birth`, `street`, `postal`, `city`, `country`, `citizenship`, `phone`, `mail`) VALUES (`Michael`, `xxx`, `male`, `20-04-93`, `Skolegade`, `4690`, `Copenhagen`, `Denmark`, `Polish`, `22222222`, `admin@admin.com` WHERE email = `xxx@gmail.com`) **Error**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE email = `xxx@gmail.com`)' at line 1

This is my file index.html with the form

```
<body>

<h1>Update record <?php echo $user->email; ?></h1>


<form action="insertdata.php" method="post">
<label>Your name: </label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<label>Your surname: </label><input type="text" name="surname" /><br />
<label>Gender: </label><input type="text" name="gender" /><br />
<label>Date of birth: </label><input type="text" name="birth" /><br />
<label>Street name: </label><input type="text" name="street" /><br />
<label>Postal: </label><input type="text" name="postal" /><br />
<label>City: </label><input type="text" name="city" /><br />
<label>Country: </label><input type="text" name="country" /><br />
<label>Citizenship: </label><input type="text" name="citizenship" /><br />
<label>Phone number: </label><input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
<label>E-mail address: </label><input type="text" name="mail" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" /> 

</form>
<?php
    if($sql){//if the update worked

echo "<b>Update successful!</b>";



}  
?>
```

And this is the code of file insertdata.php in which it finds an error:

```
<?php
// To protect any php page on your site, include main.php
// and create a new User object. It's that simple!

require_once '../includes/main.php';

$user = new User();

if(!$user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('index.php');
}

        require_once('functions.php');

        connect_db();



        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);    
        $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['surname']);  
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);    
        $birth = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['birth']);  
        $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['street']);    
        $postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postal']);    
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);    
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['country']);  
        $citizen = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['citizen']);  
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);  
        $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mail']);    
        $email = $user->email;      

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `info` (`name`, `surname`, `gender`, `birth`, `street`,         `postal`, `city`, `country`, `citizenship`, `phone`, `mail`) VALUES (`$name`, `$surname`,     `$gender`, `$birth`, `$street`, `$postal`, `$city`, `$country`, `$citizen`, `$phone`,       `$mail` WHERE email = `$email`)";


        echo $sql;

        //$result = mysql_query($con,$sql);


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 ercord added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

?>

    <a href="../tryprofile">Check</a>
```

I tried to remove the **"** from the code at the end of the line but then code is messed up and it is displaying other errors

```
 WHERE email = `$email`); "
```

e.g. that it can not read echo from the next line:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in    /data/home/vizionwe/public_html/try/insertdata.php on line 35

My deadline is until Tuesday, so I have to figure it out quick. 
I'm looking forward to see your answers and ideas.

Comment: donot use `` around info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your sql line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `info` ";
$sql.= "(`name`, `surname`, `gender`, `birth`, `street`, `postal`, `city`, `country`, `citizenship`, `phone`, `mail`) VALUES ";
$sql.= "('".$name."', '".$surname."', '".$gender."', '".$birth."', '".$street."', '".$postal."', '".$city."', '".$country."', '".$citizen."', '".$phone."', '".$mail."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you should use ' instead of ` around the values you try to put into the database.

Like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `info` (`name`, `surname`, `gender`, `birth`, `street`,         `postal`, `city`, `country`, `citizenship`, `phone`, `mail`) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$gender', '$birth', '$street', '$postal', '$city', '$country', '$citizen', '$phone', '$mail' WHERE email = '$email')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO info (name, surname, gender, birth, street, postal, city, country, citizenship, phone, mail) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$surname."', '".$gender."', '".$birth."', '".$street."', '".$postal."', '".$city."', '".$country."', '".$citizen."', '".$phone."', '".$mail."')"
```